# Why do I get a warning: "build.properties does not exist"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This appears to be something to do with the Plugin Development Environment, but I'm not writing an Eclipse Plugin.

How can I stop getting this warning?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not writing a plug-in, then you can edit the .project file and remove the Plugin Nature, and perhaps also the api tools nature if it is there.

```
<projectDescription>
    ...
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.apiAnalysisNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: After that I had to delete the project in the Project Explorer without deleting the project content on the disk and then import it back into the workspace.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this tip! Removing th whole .metadata folder deletes a lot of personal configuration, but deleting .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/_your_project_name_ is sufficient.

Comment: This will also fix other PDE build problems like `build.properties` looking for files that does not exist anymore. And for others, don't forget to delete a particular project folder and not the whole `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` directory which contains also lots of other important information.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a simple Java project? And what version of eclipse (and plugins) are you using?
Because for an EMF project (model), the build.properties won't exist until we generate the model (as [mentioned here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.emf/msg29506.html)).

Otherwise, try a full refresh of the project, and/or check if you have a file referencing a build.properties files within your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but non of the other solutions worked for me. I'm using eclipse 4.3 and I had to remove the .metadata folder. After reloading the project the warning was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/_your_project_name_ also worked for me. I had to restart my IDE (Eclipse) for me to see the changes. Rebuilding and refreshing did not reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, none of the above proposals helped. But the actual solution was surprisingly simple: in the Problems view, open the warning's context menu (right-click) and select "Delete". Confirm the standard warning that pops up, and the warning was gone, and did not re-appear again after even after "clean" and build.