# "build.properties does not exist" error in MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I using MyEclipse 8.6.1 for development my applications. I get "build.properties does not exist" errors in some project, but workspace compiled and run without problem, only error image(a red image) shown in project root. I search in frume for solve this problem, in some case say this "reason of this problem is  or  in .project file", but I don't see any problem to this file.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this by:

1. Project/Properties/Builders
   uncheck all builders
   Commit
2. Project/Properties/Builders
   re-check all builders
   Commit

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't know why I have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens on occasion if I'm playing around with files in svn and I accidentally change or remove the `.project`, `.classpath`, `.buildpath` or `.anything` files that eclipse and various IDEs based on it use. The solution I use is to create a new project with similar settings, to find the hidden files in question beginning with a dot, and to copy them from the blank project to the current one. Make sure to make a backup and also to open the dot files and change any strings that are specific to your project.

For example, here's my `.project` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>MyProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Given you were using eclipse for Java, you would only need to change `MyProjectName` accordingly and place the file in the root of your project.

Comment: what content of .buildpath or .build.properties files because when create new project in MyEclipse, that don't generate these files.

Comment: These files are invisible, so make sure to show hidden files in your OS. If they really don't show up but other hidden files do, then make sure you're creating a Java project and not a standard project, which might not have these files.

Comment: I using windows xp as OS and set show hidden files but don't see any .buildpath or build.properties in my project, only .project and .calsspath exist in my root project.

Comment: Then copy these files, edit their contents to reflect the name of your project like I've shown above, and copy/replace the existing files in your problematic project (remember to backup)

Comment: I don't see any .build or build.properties files;

Comment: Hmm... they should be created in the a folder similar to `/myworkspace/project_folder/`

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226642/why-do-i-get-a-warning-build-properties-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck everything in Project->Properties->Plug-In Development->Runtime Classpath

Answer (score 0):

a simple refresh on the project worked for me